# Change direction of line start arrow (Draw.io)

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Is it possible to alter the direction of a line start arrow.  Some diagrams would benefit from this for clarity.

e.g. [a]>------>[b] rather than [a]<------>[b]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't built in way to point both arrows in the same direction, nor is there a shape which does this in the draw.io gallery. Some possible work-arounds:

[image: using the many-to]

Use the many-to symbol to give an effect similar to an arrow

[image: use an image]

Create an image with the arrow and place it in the desired location.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  This doesn't give the result I am after but simply swaps the start arrow to an end arrow or vice versa.  I am trying to achieve an arrow on both ends of the line both pointing in the same direction.  For example: A>------>B.  Note both arrows are pointing at B.

Comment: @DanWheeler Sorry I misunderstood, I've updated my answer to provide some options.